# Splash Screen for JSP Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I have looked at a few other 'splash screen' pages but they all relate to a java applictation. I need to create a splash screen while a JSTL element loads objects into a table when the page is first loaded. If there are quite a few records it can take a while.

```
             <div class="createset">
                    <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.user.cards}" var="card">
                        <tr class="setdatarow">
                            <td class="setdata"><c:out value="${card.flashCardnum}"></c:out></td>
                            <td class="setdata"><c:out value="${card.category}"></c:out></td>
                            <td class="setdata"><c:out value="${card.card}"></c:out></td>
                            <td class="setdata"><c:out value="${card.answer}"></c:out></td>
                            <td class="setdata"><input type="checkbox" value="${card.flashCardnum}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                    </table>    
                </div>
```

I'm not sure if it is this load that takes so long or the actual retrieval of all the records in java code:

```
ArrayList<Card> usersCards = DataDAO.getCardsForUser(userAccount);
userAccount.addCards(usersCards);
session.setAttribute("user",userAccount);
```

but either way it takes really long and the page looks incomplete for a while before all the cards are loaded; as if it hasn't yet loaded up the css maybe?

edit: I think I could do it with javascript ?

Comment: Use lazy / paged loading and load pages using Ajax.

Comment: Okay I'll look into that thanks! Do you know of any good resources for lazy loading

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml